# How to merge two db with same structure but different data

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm working with phpmyadmin and I have to merge two db with same structure but different data.

The db have relation between tables (foreign key).
The data in two db may have same id, and so their foreign key.

I would like to know if it's possible merge the two db keeping all data, so, if a row already "exist", insert it with new id and update its foreign key.

thanks a lot

Comment: Think there is no convenient way. You should write something by self, that will compare data, apply changes where it necessary and than save it. You should start from core entities, and than slowly join all other tables.

Comment: ah ok...I hoped there was a easy solution. Anyway thanks for replay!

Answer (score 0):

No easy way unfortunately. If you have TableA as a foreign key to TableB, you will need to

1) Insert data from source tableA to target tableA
2) create a (temp) table to store the mapping between source tableA ids and target tableA ids
3) Use this mapping table when inserting data from tableB to convert the tableA ids to the new ones in the target db

... and so on. It can get quite hairy if you have a deep hierarchy of tables, but hopefully you get the idea. Take backups before you start.

Comment: how about duplicate rows?

Comment: Do left join on the key and only insert where null

Comment: You have structure id,name,street. Table A from first database contain row `1,Joe Blow,Green Park RD 10`, table A from second database contain `3,Joe Blow, Green Park road (10)`. They have different ID, different address, but this is same person. What should you do in this case?

Comment: I can't answer that - you need to decide what logic to use in determining what is new data and what is a match. Just use the same logic when building your mapping table. If e.g. you decide a matching name means a matching record then in this case your left join would be on name, and since it found a match you would not insert. Your mapping table would use name, and would map id 1 in the first to id 3 in the second, so and child records in other should convert 1 to 3 (and then check other fields to avoid duplication) (assuming merging first -> second)

Comment: ok, and now multiple it in 200 tables for an example. There is project in my office, where 3 developers work on synchronization more than 3 years. Of course, they have a lot of databases from different organisations, and they should do synchronization from day to day, but it is absolutely not common task, and it can not be resolved by `insert into schemA.tableA (select * from schemaB.tableA)`

Answer (score 0):

Another idea that you might want to consider is using a cursor:

1. Assume table A is the one that you want to keep and table B is the one you want to remove.
2. Declare a cursor for table B and select all the records.
3. Loop each record selected from the cursor and check. 
   Case 1: If the ID is exists on table A, insert the record to table A with same details.
   Case 2: If the ID is exists on table B, insert the record and modify the ID and foreign key.
4. Once all the records have been checked, drop table B.

Sorry, I just can give an idea at the moment.

Comment: will no work properly, info 100%.http://www.newsmo.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/800px-Arnold_schwarzenegger_train-300x225.jpg

Comment: Previously I used this on sql server and got no issue, but I haven't worked with mysql for a while.

Comment: If table A have 100 rows, table B have 150 rows, both id's is autoincrement fields, you will add to table A first 100 rows of B. Also, all FK from this rows will be lost (or how you will update them?). Second case will add rest of rows to table A, and I absolutely have no idea, how you will update FK. Also, you did not take care about duplicate rows.